# Can Redis help circumvent database connection limits

Tags: heroku, database-design, redis, architecture

I am looking at using a Heroku Postgres instance where theoretically there can be many simultaneous connections. The cost of a node that can handle that many seems too expensive.

Would deploying a Heroku Redis instance to cache certain database queries/outcomes help mitigate this issue and save costs?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following two methods.

**Connection Pool**

You can use a connection pool to limit the total connections to your database. All client fetch a connection from the pool before sending request to database. If a client CANNOT fetch a connection from the pool, it just waits for others to release the connection.

However, this method might cause some latency.

**Cache**

You can use a cache server, e.g. Redis, to cache the results from the database. If the result has been written to cache, any subsequent requests can get the result from cache quickly.

However, you should consider the following problems.

1. Do the requests to your dataset have a high `Cache Hit Ratio`? If it's high, most requests' results can be cached, and the performance is good. Otherwise, you'll get many `Cache Miss` requests, and the performance is bad.
2. Do you care about the stale data. Since the cache might NOT be consistent with database, you might get stale data from cache. If your application always needs the fresh data, you CANNOT cache the result.